# Yahoo Finance API Error 400 in Asia

Tags: api, csv, yahoo-finance, http-status-code-400

We use Yahoo Finance API CSV http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv in our financial software, to get currency exchange rates.
As of today, customers from Asia are complaining that it's not working anymore. After routing my traffic through multiple Asian countries (Japan, Malaysia etc), indeed loading the above URL gives error 400. It works just fine from EU and US though.

Anyone else having issues like that? Any idea when and if it will be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Have the same problem. We are using AWS in Singapore

Comment: We don't use AWS...we actually don't make the requests directly to Yahoo... instead, each client makes their own requests from their own device.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Yahoo's stock data API was terminated in May 2017.

I'm using Alpha Vantage now which seems great.

I've just written a blog post about it:

http://www.the-data-wrangler.com/acquiring-stock-market-data-from-alpha-vantage/